# Most appropriate way to construct overlapping dummies

Tags: categorical-data, meta-analysis, meta-regression

What would be the most appropriate way to construct dummies with theoretical overlap?

I'm doing a meta-regression of studies looking at the effect of certain interventions on X. Some studies use only women, some only men, and some a mixed population. I want to control for the fact that there can be a difference.

Is there anything inappropriate about the following construction?

```
Effect size     Men     Women    Mixed
0.35            1       0        0
0.47            0       0        1
0.22            1       0        0
0.98            0       1        0
```

The categories are mutually exclusive in coding, although not in theory (mixed has some men, some women), making analysis messy. However, I think it is important to control for study characteristics. I have a variety of considerations and reservations when I look at this, but would love additional input.

Comment: Is it possible to use the percentage of women as a continuous variable? Or do you lack that information.

Comment: Interesting. I think I have that information for some studies, but not others...but that is something I could go back and look for!

Answer (score 4):

You could probably do something like the following:

```
 Effect size     Men     Women    Men*Women

    0.35            1       0        0

    0.47            1       1        1

    0.22            1       0        0

    0.98            0       1        0
```

where Men*Women is an interaction term.

Comment: Why do you recommend this? How would the results be interpreted? What advantages would it have over the coding in the question, which also uses three indicator variables? Why is an "interaction term" needed?

Comment: In fact, this is just a different parametrization for the same underlying model.

Comment: Doesn't an interaction term imply that the combination of the two variables has some sort of interactive/exponentiating effect? I think for my particular case, peer influence is minimal; it's more about if the intervention works differently on men vs. women. So say 75% of men improve under intervention X, and only 25% of women. It's a good idea for men, probably not for women. But if I lump all studies together, I won't be able to parse that. Does that help?